# Recording 1920x1080 video on a smaller resolution monitor?

Tags: multi-monitor, monitors, gpu, resolution

I'm trying to make a basic screen recorder (with JavaScript and the MediaRecorder API), it records the actual full size of my screen really well, but the problem is is that that size is only about 1366x768, and I want the resolution of the final video to be 1920x1080.

This may seem ridiculous, but instead of making the actual video quality itself 1920x1080, I just want the video file to be 1920x1080, with the rest either being artificially scaled, or better yet, drawn in a box within a larger, black screen (if that makes sense). The point of this is for youtube resolution, which downsizes 1366 back to 720, but if I put the 1366x768 in a larger 1920x1080 box, then it would keep the resolution.

So using Linux, Lubuntu I need to know if there's any way to "fake" a higher resolution, just for the sake of recording a higher-scaled video in it, even if it doesn't adjust the actual resolution. (AKA I need system applications to think its a 1920x1080 monitor, even if its not)

Again, two possibilities, #1 either literally make everything "stretched" or #2 somehow draw the current display in a larger surrounding black rectangle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but can you post-process the video somehow, to increase the resolution?

Comment: @Time4Tea I was thinking of donig something like that with ffmpeg, but #1 I couldn't find the right command arguments for it (that didn't distort the aspect rtaio) and #2 I would *prefer* it's done in real time with JavaScript, but theoretically if someone can provide the correct FFMPEG arguments to make a new video 1920 x 1080, with the original video, in its original resolution, in the center of it, surrounded by black sides, that would be good too